# How to make PC unzip a downloaded file with one click in Chrome? Macs do this, why not PCs?

Tags: zip, unzip, 7zip

How do you make a PC unzip a downloaded file **with one click** in Chrome? Macs do this, why not PCs?

On my Mac, when I download a .zip file, it shows in the bottom bar of Chrome. If I click once on that download in the Chrome bottom bar, it unzips the archive into the same directory ("Downloads") without any further interaction from me.

How can a PC user get a file to unzip with that same convenience? Everything I've tried requires you to go to make two or three steps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it. It is not nearly as seamless and quick as on a Mac, but it works without *any* user interaction by monitoring your download folder for archives. When one shows up in the folder, it automatically unzips the archive and can optionally delete the .zip, or run a command line, or what-have-you. On a slow PC I tested it on, it took about 40 seconds to recognize there was a new archive and to process it. Hopefully that's faster on faster PCs.

Here are the basics:

1. download ExtractNow onto PC from http://www.extractnow.com
2. in the Settings tabs, under Monitor, select the path to the folder want to monitor and check the "Automatically extract" checkbox.

That's basically it.

Additionally you can run a command. **I needed to do something a little unusual** - open an .html file from the just-expanded archive using Microsoft Word - and I was able to get it to do that automatically. Here's what I entered in the Process tab under the "Archive operation complete" section:

1. check the "Run a program" checkbox
2. in the Command: box, enter this:
   winword {ArchiveFolder}"{ArchiveName}.html"

You can tweak that for your circumstances. The point is that **ExtractNow can pass info about the archive (the name, the path, etc.) in bracketed, named variables so that you can use them to invoke other commands or processing**.

I don't love the time lag, but it completely does what I wanted and more. Cheers!